# Where do I store my private keys?

Tags: encryption

I have one GPG Personal key, two SSH RSA keys, and one Machine Owner Key. What would be the best way to keep them safe if I don't want to take them off my hard drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encrypt them (perhaps just use the standard utility to zip them up and use a password, or even several layers) and then place them somewhere where you know where they are but others would not, if you want to keep them really hidden then give them names that don't make them look out of the ordinary, you could also put a `.` infront of each in the filename to make them hidden on the Linux and Unix file systems.

Though normally you will be asked to set a passphrase for them so they will have already been encrypted.

I just store mine though in the GNOME Keyring, that keeps them reasonably well protected and encrypted. But then people do know where to find them, so it's your choice really.

Comment: Yeah, I did encrypt them with a passphrase.  Just one thing, I only need to put the public keys in my .ssh folder, right?

Comment: Also, how about putting them in the Gnome keyring? My SSH and GPG keys already appear in it, but the MOKs don't.

Comment: @Somebody: That's where I store them, and I'm a Paranoid Panda, so you should trust me. ;P

Answer (score 3):

You may install `keepassx`.  That's exactly what it does.  It encrypts and stores all kinds of passwords and you can also use keyfiles for extra protection.

`sudo apt-get install keepassx`